# Reading Owner Info

Tags: android

Android users can enter arbitrary text into **Settings > Security > Owner Info**, at least in Jelly Bean. How can I read that string from an app?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
final String[] SELF_PROJECTION = new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, };
```

Cursor is :

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query( Profile.CONTENT_URI, SELF_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

now just do a simple cursor.moveToFirst():

and then fetch the contact id via `cursor.getString(0)` and the contact name via `cursor.getString(1)`

Comment: That only returns the user's name. They are able to enter arbitrary text that gets displayed as a scrolling marquee on their lock screen. I wish to read that text programmatically.